# Why getting ____ cannot be null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm on learning stage and just start making little app contains single entity. While test on postman I keep getting an error:
Column 'account_number' cannot be null
Although I enter accountNumber.
I follow entity & related classed hereunder:
My excuse if I make something missing due to lack of knowledge. Grateful for an advise

PrimaryAccount

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "primary_account")
public class PrimaryAccount {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "account_number")
private String accountNumber;
@Column(name = "account_balance")
private BigDecimal accountBalance;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "primaryAccount", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private List<PrimaryTransaction> primaryTransactionList;
Getter&Setting&Constructor
```

AccountService

```
public interface AccountService {
ResponseEntity<String> createPrimaryAccount();
}
```

AccountServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

@Autowired
private PrimaryAccountDao primaryAccountDao;

public ResponseEntity<String> createPrimaryAccount() {
    PrimaryAccount primaryAccount = new PrimaryAccount();
    primaryAccount.setAccountNumber(primaryAccount.getAccountNumber());
    primaryAccount.setAccountBalance(primaryAccount.getAccountBalance());
    primaryAccountDao.save(primaryAccount);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Record entered");
}
```

@Controller
public class AccountController {

```
@Autowired
private AccountService accountService;

@PostMapping("/primaryAccount")
public ResponseEntity<String> primaryAccount(PrimaryAccount primaryAccount) {
    return accountService.createPrimaryAccount();
}
```

PrimarAccountDao

```
public interface PrimaryAccountDao extends CrudRepository<PrimaryAccount, Long> {
   PrimaryAccount findByAccountNumber (long accountNumber);
}
```

on postman side I just make as follow:

```
 {
    "AccountNumber": "89000",
    "AccountBalance": 2000.00
}
```

Error:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 
'account_number' cannot be null
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException
(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
at 
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException
(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:
8.0.26]at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal
(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java- 
8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal
(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) ~[mysql-connector-java- 
8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal
(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040) ~[mysql-connector-java- 
8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate
(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1350) ~[mysql-connector-java- 
8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate
(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025) ~[mysql-connector-java- 
8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate
(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate
(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.
executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core- 
5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert
 (AbstractEntityPersister.java:3298) ~[hibernate-core- 
 5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert
(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3825) ~[hibernate-core- 
5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute
(EntityInsertAction.java:107) ~[hibernate-core- 
5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at 
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions
(ActionQueue.java:604) 
~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1
(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core- 
5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) 
~ na:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions
(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core- 
5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.
performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344) ~ 
[hibernate- 
core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush
(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core- 
5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.
fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99) ~[hibernate- 
core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush
(SessionImpl.java:1362) ~[hibernate-core- 
 5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at 
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453) 
~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at 
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion
(SessionImpl.java:3212) ~[hibernate-core- 
5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion
(SessionImpl.java:2380) ~[hibernate-core- 
 5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.
beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:448) ~ 
[hibernate- 
core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.
JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion
Callback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.
JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300
(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate- 
core- 
5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.
JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriver
ControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.
java:281) 
 ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit
(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core- 
 5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit
(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
at 
 org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransaction
Manager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~ 
 [spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
```

Comment: Just a tip: a string "2000.00" for a `new BigDecimal("2000.00")` will know the correct precision of 2. A double literal has no precision, for instance printing 1.2 could output 1.1999998.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You project has basic programming fundamental issue. Update your project like this,

```
public interface AccountService {
    ResponseEntity<String> createPrimaryAccount(PrimaryAccount primaryAccount);
}
```

```
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

   @Autowired
   private PrimaryAccountDao primaryAccountDao;

   public ResponseEntity<String> createPrimaryAccount(PrimaryAccount primaryAccount) {
       primaryAccountDao.save(primaryAccount);
       return ResponseEntity.ok("Record entered");
   }
}
```

```
@Autowired
private AccountService accountService;

@PostMapping("/primaryAccount")
public ResponseEntity<String> primaryAccount(@RequestBody PrimaryAccount primaryAccount) {
    return accountService.createPrimaryAccount(primaryAccount);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are instantiating the `primaryAccount` and setting it with the value it already has, which is in fact null.
You need to pass the parameter from Controller to Service as follows:

```java
public interface AccountService {
    ResponseEntity<String> createPrimaryAccount(PrimaryAccount primaryAccount);
}
```

```java
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

@Autowired
private PrimaryAccountDao primaryAccountDao;

public ResponseEntity<String> createPrimaryAccount(PrimaryAccount primaryAccount) {
    primaryAccountDao.save(primaryAccount);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Record entered");
}
```

```java
@Controller 
public class AccountController {

   @Autowired
   private AccountService accountService;

   @PostMapping("/primaryAccount")
   public ResponseEntity<String> primaryAccount(@RequestBody PrimaryAccount primaryAccount) {
      return accountService.createPrimaryAccount(primaryAccount);
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Your JSON must be changed to:

```json
{
    "accountNumber": "89000",
    "accountBalance": 2000.00
}
```

Why? Unless you use some `@JsonProperty` annotations, the attributes in the JSON must match the name of each property in your model.

One suggestion: use DTOs instead of the Entities in your Controller layer. You can read some reason [here](https://codeopinion.com/why-use-dtos-data-transfer-objects/).

Comment: Tks, but it doesn't work. error I get is: java: method createPrimaryAccount in interface com.accountingproject.service.AccountService cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: com.accountingproject.entity.PrimaryAccount
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length...................Server starts work if I pass same parameters in AccountService: ResponseEntity<String> createPrimaryAccount(PrimaryAccount primaryAccount); but again same error persist if I post transaction that is account_number not null

Comment: Yes, you need to change the interface you are implementing (I've edited my answer). Now that you shared your JSON, there is another thing you need to change, please check my answer.